# Facebook share dialog only takes 3 images

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I made a simple test page with 5 images defined in the OG tags : http://morinfa.free.fr/fbtest.html

What I want to do is manually specify the images that Facebook should display in the share dialog. That's why the images are not in the HTML body.

The Facebook debugger correctly shows the 5 images defined in the OG tags :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmorinfa.free.fr%2Ffbtest.html

In the share dialog, why only 3 images are displayed ?

Comment: I can't find any official statement from Facebook on this issue... But I do see many people asking the same question. It could simply be a hard limit that Facebook has enforced.

Comment: What is strange is that this limit of 3 images is not applied when no og:image tags are specified. It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: That might be worth a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)...

Comment: Bug opened here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1406417349576517

Comment: Facebook answer : We are prioritizing bugs based on impact to the developer community. As this bug report has not received much attention from other developers, we are closing it so as to better focus on the top issues. There is a good chance your issue is due to an implementation problem in which case you can try to find help on Stack Overflow (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/)